# Magento2: Custom comapre button functionality

Tags: magento2, compare, checkbox

How to add custom compare button with check-box. The page should be not refreshing.

Please check below screenshot

[image]

My Magento v2.0.17

Comment: https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/ajax-suite-magento-2/

This will help you

Comment: Ok, I will check and let ou know.

Comment: I have installed the extension. Got the error at front side **Object DOMDocument should be created**. @MukeshPrajapati

Comment: Tigren_Core folder missing in extension zip file. Is important?